# Load a collection once from db, use throughout site in jsp

Tags: jsp, mongodb, caching, memcached

I am using JSP and Mongodb. I want to load the mongodb collection once and use it through my website. So, every time a query is raised it should not create the collection object again and again..
I know this has something to do with cached memory, but I am sorry I dont have any idea on that.

Also, I have a model binary file, which I want to load once and use it through out. I guess both can be done in similar way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a cache solution like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) or [infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/) instead of even thinking on build your own.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest if it works for you, would be to put the mongodb collection in the session. You can put any object value(including mongodb collection), named by a string key into the session.
As for your binary file, you could read the contents of the binary into a string and then again put that in session.
In either case, you could then check if the objects are present in the session before trying to load it.